# How can I use my Azure AD app from another tenant?

Tags: .net, azure, multi-tenant, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am developing a native app that has to display the Office 365 groups the user is a member of. For this, I call the Microsoft Graph API which requires authentication. I'm using the ADAL library.

The permissions needed require admin consent.
Everything works fine for users from my tenant, but when I try to authenticate with an account of another tenant it doesn't work. It keeps giving this result:

> Correlation ID: 9780ed24-9d24-4604-b8bf-28a02c2ea580
>
> Timestamp: 2017-04-14 12:05:45Z
>
> AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' was not found in the directory XXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com

even if I use an admin account on first connection. I am never asked for consent and the app is not registered on the other tenant.

---

The app is registered as Native so it should be multi-tenant and I pass "/common" as the tenant in the authority.

I also tried to register an app with the same specifications on the other tenant, gave admin consent on the permissions and it worked as well.

Here is how I retrieve the access token:

```
private static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(graphResource, clientID, redirectURI, PromptBehavior.RefreshSession);
        var accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
        return accessToken;
    }
```

Is it a problem within the code? The parameters? Do the other tenants need some 'special azure subscription' I'm not aware of?

In short: **How do I get it to work for other tenants?**

**Edit**: I tried to manually add the "prompt=admin_consent" to the request, like this:

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(graphResource, clientID, redirectURI,PromptBehavior.RefreshSession, UserIdentifier.Any, "prompt=admin_consent");
```

But it triggers an error saying that there is a "Duplicate query parameter 'prompt' in extraQueryParameters"

Comment: Can you include the CorrelationId and Timestamp from the error message?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret  Yes, done.

Comment: How did you create the native client app? What interface?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret It is a .net winform  app.

Comment: I meant: What interface did you use to register the native client app registered in Azure AD?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Oh ok, sorry. I used the Azure portal https://portal.azure.com, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in the new Azure portal when registering native client applications.

These are currently (as of 2017-04-14) being created as single-tenant applications. Since the Azure portal doesn't expose the "multi-tenant" toggle for native client applications, you need to update the app manifest or use Azure AD PowerShell to do this.

**Making an app multi-tenant from the manifest**

1. In the Azure portal, from the settings blade for your native client application, click the **Manifest** option.

   [image]
2. Update the `availableToOtherTenants` value to `true`.

   [image]
3. Save the manifest.

   [image]

**Making an app multi-tenant with Azure AD PowerShell**

1. Download the Azure AD PowerShell v2 module (AzureAD): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0
2. Run the following:

   ```
   $appId = "<app ID>"
   $app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
   Set-AzureADApplicatoin -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -AvailableToOtherTenants $true
   ```

That should patch it up. Wait a bit, then try again.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! When I checked the manifest, the "AvailableToOtherTenants" was indeed at "false". Who would have known? Especially since every doc I have found so far stated that native apps are automatically multi-tenant.

Comment: They *are* supposed to be created as multi-tenant by default. This is a known issue in the new (preview) portal. It will be addressed soon.